# How to generate UIMap.Designer.cs file in visual studio 2010 using UIMap.uitest file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I'm new guy to using visual studio 2010. I want to generate the UIMap.Designer.cs and UIMap.cs files using the given UIMap.uitest file(which is like .xml file). I tried in so many ways but, i can't. Can i generate those files from UIMap.uitest file using some dll files or any codes are available....? Please guide me.....

Thanks is advance...
Selvam.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to create the files programmatically or are you just wanting to create them in Visual Studio?

Comment: Why do you want that? Is it because you edited or deleted them?

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398062.aspx):

> UIMap.Designer.cs
>
> This file contains code that is automatically created by the Coded UI
>   Test Builder when a test is created. This file is re-created every
>   time that a test changes, so that it is not a file in which you can
>   add or modify code.

The same is true for UIMap.cs

Comment: Thanks Scott... Is Coded UI Test Builder a dll file or any other file..?

Comment: But I think those files(UIMap.Designer.cs and UIMap.cs) are generated only while we are recording and when we are creating the method for that recorded script.... If this is right, those files are generated by the UIMap.uitest file.... am I right..?..

Comment: It looks as though you are right... this has several How To's and other guides: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2010/02/11/content-index-for-coded-ui-test.aspx